# Attempting a twitter application for android using this tutorial

Tags: java, android, maven, twitter, twitter4j

I've been trying to use twitter4J and this tut (http://java-tutorial.ch/framework/twitter-with-java-tutorial) in attempting a simple little app. I'm pretty familiar with the basics of android. What I really don't understand is where I put twitter4J (I'm guessing the entire unzipped file into the root of the project) and what do to get it to "talk" with the program. As twiiter4J states "Just add twitter4j-core-2.2.5.jar to your application classpath." Last but not least is this piece of instruction from the tutorial as well "To build and create our application we will use Maven. In Maven the resources are located in src/main/resources."

If someone could help me out that would be awesome as I'm trying to really get this done by tonight, but I've spent about 4 hours trying to come up with some sort of way to get this to work and I just can't get it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Gave up on that current tutorial just because it wasn't really working out that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation for the [Android Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to get it all going. That tutorial is pretty bad though I have to say..

Answer (score 1):

http://maven.apache.org/

[Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath)

...

Answer (score 1):

Well possibly you have to unzip the file if its a .ZIP file. If it is a .JAR file then all you do is add it to the build path of your project, or add a libs folder to your project and the drop the JAR into it and add it to the build path of your project.(the recommended way)

Get more info on MAVEN here http://maven.apache.org/